# apps script getValue contents only not formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am very new to Google Apps scripting.

I am trying to copy the contents of a sheet into another sheet. This code works without any problem but its copy with formula and i need only the value,

```
function CopyandPasteToB() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName('F1');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('F2');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A52:E52");
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  if (rlast === mysheet.getMaxRows()) mysheet.insertRowsAfter(rlast, 1); // Avoid error if last row with content is last row of the sheet
  var destRange = mysheet.getRange(rlast + 1, 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid the `copyTo()` in that case. Get the values with `getDisplayValues()` ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)) and then paste that into your new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You have to use these versions of copyTo() method:

[copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

Or

[copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#copytodestination,-options)

> Use the `CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES` to only copy the value instead of the actual formula. Or add `{contentsOnly:true}` as the option inside the `copyTo()` method, separated by a comma after the range.

### Sample

```
function CopyandPasteToB() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName('F1');
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('F2');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A52:E52");
  var rlast = mysheet.getLastRow();
  if (rlast === mysheet.getMaxRows()) mysheet.insertRowsAfter(rlast, 1); // Avoid error if last row with content is last row of the sheet
  var destRange = mysheet.getRange(rlast + 1, 1);
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  //Or use this other copyTo() version below
  //sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly:true});
};
```

### Result

> F2 Sheet:

[image]

> F1 Sheet:

[image]